# Sharing image with Facebook from Windows Store App

Tags: facebook, windows-8, share, windows-store-apps

I'm developing an application that must share a picture with Facebook.

Following the guidelines of Windows 8, I must use the Share Charm (text, html, image and file). Basically the idea is to build sources apps they can share information and target apps that are capable of receiving this information.

[Turning the sample from Microsoft](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84), which allows sharing of information types is only possible to share links with Facebook using People app.

I found three possible solutions to this problem:
1 - Wait for Facebook to launch an official app for Windows 8 to receive all these information types;
2 - Wait for Microsoft to include sharing these types of information in the People app.
3 - Create a target application that implements the Facebook API.

Finally, I would like to know if you have had this kind of problem and how they solved.

Comment: I am thinking about this kind of sharing for a long time now and I think the best would be to create an app that would be able to do this. Adding capabilities to be able to share to many many social network sites! I think it would be fun to build something like this.

Comment: This is my first solution, but i don't know if microsoft agree with that. For me is more easy if Microsoft allow People app sharing with Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this library... [Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/)
I think it will give you what you want